# react html5 audio not picking up external file

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm trying to play audio from an external source (in this case NASA). I know the address is correct because if I hard code it my code work. But injecting the URL via state does nothing. Any suggestions?

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="music">
            <h1>Audio</h1>
            <br />
            <p>Sound source = {this.state.source}</p>
            <audio controls>
                <source src={this.state.source} />
            </audio>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like your code just works. You might be loosing the `state` of your component somewhere. Here is a React snippet that simply runs your code.

```js
class AudioTest extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      source: props.url
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="music">
        <h1>Audio</h1>
        <br />
        <p>Sound source = {this.state.source}</p>
        <audio controls>
            <source src={this.state.source} />
        </audio>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <AudioTest url="https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/a3fd5f178b7eb68b9dba4da9711f05a714efc966?cid=ed36a056ee504173a3889b2e55cbd461" />,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this will help you fix your issue!